# Star Trek - X-shaped Item on Regula/Orbital Office Starbases

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

On Regula/Orbital Office design starbases (we see them in the various Star Trek films and even in some of the series), what is that X-shaped thing we see on the side of the upper structure? See my picture below.I've been curious about this since I first watched Star Trek years ago.

[image: What is that X-shaped protusion?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm trying to find a better picture of a ship leaving a *Federation* starbase, but what you're looking at is basically the (lit) interior of the dock, seen through the partially closed doors.

You can see a similar looking entrance here (from TNG: Relics).

[image]
<sub><sup>**TNG: Relics - Dyson Sphere entrance.**</sup></sub>

---

On the [FASA RPG '*Regula-1 Orbital Station deckplans*'](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Regula-1_Orbital_Station_Deckplans) (non-canon but based on conversations with the show's model designers), you can see that this entrance leads directly into the Deck 8 shuttlebay.

[image]

Comment: But if that's the case, then the doors are always partially open. Every time we see that starbase model, the doors are just sitting partially open. (BTW, this shot is from the Dyson Sphere doors in the TNG episode "Relics".

Comment: Because in reality it was a flat, slightly translucent [panel with lights behind it](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/b/b1/Orbital_office_complex_model.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110531064300&path-prefix=en). Note that within the world of Trek, force-fields can be used to keep air in.